# Laravel Passport: 401 Unauthenticated, but encryption keys are the same

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have a weird problem with Passport authentication deploying my application to a new site, in spite of the fact that I haven't had a problem with this before.

I'm using Passport's password grant feature to log in to the application (Laravel 5.4). This happens by the user posting his username/password as JSON to the site, and from there it posts those credentials to OAuth/token to get the API key for the site. This has worked fine in the past, and my OAuth keys are committed to the repository.

The other day I managed to deploy the site to a new server (with the same OAuth keys), regenerated (I think) the app key, loaded my data that has the encrypted passwords, and authentication worked fine. Today, however, I did the same thing on a different branch and now logging in returns 401 Unauthorized.

I've done nearly every permutation I could think of: delete the OAuth keys, regenerate app key, reinstall passport, and yet the app refuses to log in. I don't believe it has anything to do with the source code because no changes I made on this branch would affect the login system.

I even tried copying the working site's app key and OAuth keys to the broken site still don't work.

What makes this even more puzzling to me is that I have another site with a *different* app key, *different* OAuth keys, but the same data, and the login system works fine.

I don't understand the league/oauth2 package enough to understand why this isn't working. What am I missing?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: Check the callback URL on the API for your client. If you are on a different domnain now you'll need to change that.

Comment: Are you routes in web.php or api.php?  Also what type of middleware is doing your checks?  The standard 'Auth:Api'?  Need more details.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I believe the callback url is just localhost; maybe setting that manually might help?

Comment: @BradGoldsmith the route that actually posts internally to /oauth/token is in web.php. Web's middlewares are EncryptCookies, AddQueuedCookiesToResponse, ShareErrorsFromSession, SubstituteBindings. Api is just `throttle:60,1`, and `auth:api`

Comment: @mkrell ok my bad I misread the question I apologize.  I had a very similar problem when I was granting client_credentials for clients to hit my API.  Have you tried php artisan passport:keys to regenerate the passport encryption keys?

Comment: @BradGoldsmith I actually have, but I think i'm on to the reason at the suggestion of a colleague. The broken site is actually an attempt to move an existing site to a new server (so the broken site has the same domain), but the DNS hasn't actually changed. My code says to post to `url('/oauth/token')`. In other words.... **to the old site**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, bad code doesn't pay.

What I didn't mention was that the site I'm trying to deploy is an attempt to move a domain over to a new server. Both the broken site and it's active sister site have the same domain name. This is the code that posts to my own domains `/oauth/token` endpoint:

```
$username = Input::json('username');
$password = Input::json('password');

$page = Input::get('page');

$client = Client::find(2);

$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [   # <-- see the problem?
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => '2',
            'client_secret' => $client->secret,
            'username'      => $username,
            'password'      => $password,
            'scope'         => '',
        ],
    ]);

#...
```

The problem is rather hilarious. Since the DNS hasn't switched for the site yet, the requests to my own site **are going to the old site, not this one**. Hence I'm getting back `Unauthenticated`. Because I'm not.

The solution was to edit the `/etc/hosts` file on the server to point the domain to itself. That way, any calls to its own api will actually go its own api. Problem solved.